# Elasticsearch Spring repository search using multiple fields

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application connected to an Elasticsearch instance containing [this sample data](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/src/test/resources/accounts.json?raw=true). I am currently able to search for a specific field, but the moment I add the second one in the request, I don't have any results (each of the fields are fine on their own). How can I get the correct results?

Here are my classes:

```
@Document(indexName = "bank", type = "account", replicas = 0)
public class Account {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private long accountNumber;
    private long balance;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private long age;
    private String gender;
    private String address;
    private String employer;
    private String email;
    private String city;
    private String state;

}


public interface AccountRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Account, String> {

    Page<Account> findByGenderAndStateAllIgnoreCase(String gender, String state, Pageable pageable);

}


@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Account save(Account account) {
        return repository.save(account);
    }

    @Override
    public Account findOne(String id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Account> findAll(PageRequest request) {
        return repository.findAll(request).getContent();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Account> findByGenderAndState(String gender, String state, PageRequest request) {
        return repository.findByGenderAndStateAllIgnoreCase(gender, state, request).getContent();
    }

}


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bank")
public class BankController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping("/accounts")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Collection<Account> accounts(@RequestParam(name = "gender", required = false, defaultValue = "*") String gender,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "state", required = false, defaultValue = "*") String state,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") int size) {
        return accountService.findByGenderAndState(gender, state, new PageRequest(page, size));
    }

}
```

Here is the query that is sent to Elasticsearch from Spring Boot:

```
[
  {
    "from": 20,
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "f",
              "fields": [
                "gender"
              ],
              "default_operator": "and"
            }
          },
          {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "dc",
              "fields": [
                "state"
              ],
              "default_operator": "and"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was querying for the page #1, instead of #0. The results are showing correctly now.